# Vary length of arrows in Matplotlib Axes3D.quiver plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any way of varying the lengths of individual arrows in a quiver plot?

I have created a plot using:

```
lines_to_draw = list of numpy 3d vectors
xs, ys, zs    = list of coordinates
us, vs, ws    = list of displacements

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
for line in lines_to_draw:
    ax.plot(line[:,0], line[:,1], line[:,2], color='green'
ax.quiver(xs, ys, zs, us, vs, ws)
```

It looks like this (axes turned off):
[image: Quiver plot]

The problem is that all the arrows look to be the same magnitude. The docs suggest that this is probably the case (specifically the `length` argument):

> Axes3D.quiver(*args, **kwargs)
>   Plot a 3D field of arrows.
>
> call signatures:
>
> quiver(X, Y, Z, U, V, W, **kwargs) Arguments:
>
> X, Y, Z: The x, y and z coordinates of the arrow locations
>
> U, V, W: The direction vector that the arrow is pointing The arguments could be
>   array-like or scalars, so long as they they can be broadcast together.
>   The arguments can also be masked arrays. If an element in any of
>   argument is masked, then that corresponding quiver element will not be
>   plotted.
>
> Keyword arguments:
>
> length: [1.0 | float] The length of each quiver, default to 1.0, the
>   unit is the same with the axes
>
> arrow_length_ratio: [0.3 | float] The
>   ratio of the arrow head with respect to the quiver, default to 0.3 Any
>   additional keyword arguments are delegated to LineCollection

Just for clarification, the magnitude of the vectors differs by up to a factor of 30. So there should be a very visible difference.

Comment: What happens when you use the length argument?

Comment: It scales all of the arrows equally, sorry, should have mentioned that.

I looked more into `matplotlib` on Github and I'm pretty sure that it normalises each `(u_i, v_i, w_i)^T` vector.

Comment: You're right. You could break up the data by length classes and `quiver` each separately. Although, looking at this, is that useful for data display? Isn't the reader likely to be confused between short arrows and arrows nearly perpendicular to the plane of the image? Maybe color variation instead?

Comment: I should have also specified my use case too. These won't be used for rendering single images. It's for visualising the normal modes of a molecule and will always be done by rotating the image so that we can account for projection.

I'm submitting a PR to matplotlib, since the maintainer thinks that the vectors shouldn't be normalised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be possible in the next major MPL release, see this [pull request](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/5458).

Hack: You could edit the respective MPL files on your system, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33635183/1150303) answer.

Alternatively: issue an individual `ax.quiver` command for each arrow, with individual `length` attribute. This is not very efficient but in some cases this may help, already.

Comment: That's great. I was actually the person who raised the issue referenced, but got sidetracked and didn't actually make and submit the PR.