# How to update 3D arrow animation in matplotlib

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, 3d

I am trying to reproduce the left plot of [this animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q0qrU4nprB0) in python using matplotlib.

[image]

I am able to generate the vector arrows using the 3D quiver function, but as I [read here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4211), it does not seem possible to set the lengths of the arrows. So, my plot does not look quite right:

[image]

So, the question is: how do I generate a number of 3D arrows with different lengths? Importantly, can I generate them in such a way so that I can easily modify for each frame of the animation?

Here's my code so far, with the not-so-promising 3D quiver approach:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d

ax1 = plt.subplot(111,projection='3d')

t = np.linspace(0,10,40)

y = np.sin(t)
z = np.sin(t)
line, = ax1.plot(t,y,z,color='r',lw=2)

ax1.quiver(t,y,z, t*0,y,z)
plt.show()
```

Comment: is there a length variable in your data

Comment: To match the other plot, the length of the vectors should be sufficient to extent them to the x (or t this case) axis. I was thinking that the length would probably not actually be necessary for drawing the arrows, but if it is, it can be easily calculated as length = np.sqrt(y\*\*2 + z**2).

Comment: Unfortunately, it would seem not (at the moment):
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4211

Comment: The problem is that mplot3d always normalizes arrow lengths. I know this is inelegant but if you manually edit `mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py` and change this line `norm = math.sqrt(u ** 2 + v ** 2 + w ** 2)` to `norm = 1` it would work with your current code. I don't know why the developers won't add a flag to perform normalization only when desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Azad suggests, an inelegant, but effective, solution is to simply edit the mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py to remove the normalization. Since I didn't want to mess with my actual matplotlib installation, I simply copied the axes3d.py file to the same directory as my other script and modified the line

```
norm = math.sqrt(u ** 2 + v ** 2 + w ** 2)
```

to

```
norm = 1
```

(Be sure to change the correct line. There is another use of "norm" a few lines higher.) Also, to get axes3d.py to function correctly when it's outside of the mpl directory, I changed

```
from . import art3d
from . import proj3d
from . import axis3d
```

to

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import art3d
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axis3d
```

And here is the nice animation that I was able to generate (not sure what's going wrong with the colors, it looks fine before I uploaded to SO).

[image]

And the code to generate the animation:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import axes3d_hacked

ax1 = plt.subplot(111,projection='3d')
plt.ion()
plt.show()

t = np.linspace(0,10,40)

for index,delay in enumerate(np.linspace(0,1,20)):
    y = np.sin(t+delay)
    z = np.sin(t+delay)

    if delay > 0:
        line.remove()
        ax1.collections.remove(linecol)

    line, = ax1.plot(t,y,z,color='r',lw=2)
    linecol = ax1.quiver(t,y,z, t*0,y,z)

    plt.savefig('images/Frame%03i.gif'%index)
    plt.draw()

plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

Now, if I could only get those arrows to look prettier, with nice filled heads. But that's a separate question...

EDIT: In the future, matplotlib will not automatically normalize the arrow lengths in the 3D quiver per this [pull request](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/5458).

Comment: you don't have to use any extra imports but if your interpreter was open before the edit you should close it and open it again

Comment: I changed the imports because I moved the location of the axes3d.py file to the same directory as my script. I wanted to avoid actually changing the source code of my matplotlib distribution.

Comment: No worries - just making sure I understood you correctly. Thanks again for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to call `ax.quiever` on each arrow, individually - with each call having an own `length` attribute. This is not very efficient but it will get you going.

And there's no need to change MPL-code