# Varying arrow length in 3D quiver

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

I try to have arrows of different length created by a single quiver command in matplotlib (for 3D). For the **2D** version of quiver I get arrows of different length, but they are not scaled right:

```
x = linspace(0, 10, 11)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
ax.quiver(x, zeros(x.shape), zeros(x.shape), x)
```

[image]

How do I get the right scaling for the 2D version (arrows of length 1, 2, 3, 4, ...)?

For **3D** all the arrows have exactly the same length and I can only change the length of the entire set by using the `length` argument:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.quiver(x, zeros(x.shape), zeros(x.shape), zeros(x.shape), x, zeros(x.shape), pivot='tail')
ax.set_ylim([-1, 2])
ax.view_init(90, -90)
```

[image]

How can I have sizes according to the `u, v, w` arguments that I set?

Comment: The quiver arguments are X,Y,u,v, so your line should read :  `ax.quiver(x, np.zeros(x.shape), np.zeros(x.shape), np.ones(x.shape))` if you want arrows of the same length.

Comment: Or is it that you don't like the scaling of the head of the arrow? Then you need to look at `(shaft) width`. `head length`, `head width` are multiples of `width`. See the documentation here: `http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html`

Comment: All I'm concerned about is the length of the arrows. For both cases I expect arrows of the length 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, .... For the 2D command I get lengths of 0.002, 0.004, ..., 0.02 instead (and it depends on the ylims that I set before). For the 3D command all the arrows have the same length of 1, regardless of the `v` I'm setting. `v` only seems to influence the direction of the arrow.

Comment: I got it now:)  Had that problem also years ago. Quiver rescales your arrows so that the longest ones are a fit to the next grid point. Look at both `scale` and `scale units` in `http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html`.

Comment: This was a good hint. This way the 2D version is working well: `ax.quiver(x, zeros(x.shape), zeros(x.shape), x, scale_units='y', scale=1.0)` However, the `mplot3d` version of `quiver` doesn't have these arguments. So I still can not define the length there.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997533/vary-length-of-arrows-in-matplotlib-axes3d-quiver-plot?rq=1 for some relevant info regarding this issue